The PostgreSQL is not supported by drogon, please install the development library first
I'm working on a C++ project using the Drogon framework and Neon Database (PostgreSQL), and I'm configuring my project with CMake. However, when I try to run my project, I receive an error indicating that the PostgreSQL development library is not supported or not found by Drogon.
C++ code:
  drogon::app().createDbClient("postgresql", // type
                               "[neon url...]",  // host
                                5432,         // port
                               "[dbname]",     // dbname
                               "users_owner",       // user
                               "[password-placeholder]",   // passwd
                               5);           // connNum

Cmake:
# use cmake -S . -B build
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(PatrolSystem)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")


find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
find_package(Drogon REQUIRED)



add_executable(untitled main.cpp
        # ... other source files ...
)


# Link the necessary libraries

target_link_libraries(untitled PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL Drogon::Drogon)

Error Message:
The PostgreSQL is not supported by drogon, please install the development library first.
I have verified that PostgreSQL is installed on my system and I've tried reinstalling the PostgreSQL development libraries. Despite this, the issue persists.
Update: I am able to access the database via the CLI
What steps can I take to resolve this error and ensure a successful build?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

you need to install the PG develeppement library before building your program
    PostgreSQL's native C library libpq needs to be installed. The installation is as follows:

ubuntu 16: sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-all
ubuntu 18: sudo apt-get install postgresql-all
centOS 7: yum install postgresql-devel
MacOS: brew install postgresql
Windows conanfile: libpq/13.4

drogonframework-Installation

I already did via brew

"I have verified that PostgreSQL is installed on my system and I've tried reinstalling the PostgreSQL development libraries. Despite this, the issue persists."

are you using mac ? if so the need to install the same arch (arm64 or i686) (brew arm64)

Try recompiling Drogon after installing the Postgres libraries.
